# How to retrieve data from firebase straight into the app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-application

I am new to flutter. I want to retrieve data from firebase firestore database and display it in the application. My requirement is to display the data in the form of a text in the screen. I have attached the my code below for a better understanding.

Note : I have already configured firebase in my project.

Code :

```
  class dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _dashboardState createState() => _dashboardState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _dashboardState extends State<dashboard> {
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData screen = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 250),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: screen.size.width,
                  // height: 20.0,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: (const Text(
                    'I need the data retreievd from firebase firestore to be displayed here.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 1.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30.0),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ProfilePage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 5.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 25.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 390,
                  height: 450,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green.shade100,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        await authService.signOut();
      }),
      //  : _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.read_more),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.green[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You canretrieve data from firebase firestore database and display it in the application directly.

```
SteamBuilder(
steam:query(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection_name').
doc('doc_id').snapshot());
builder(context,snapshot){
return Text(snapshot.data.docs[0].get('field');
}
)
```

Comment: Hi, i tried adding this to my code. But i got some errors while trying to add this into my code.

Comment: what kind of errors please describe so i can help you.

Comment: Sure! 

Error 1 : 

The named parameter 'builder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.dartmissing_required_argument

Error 2 :

The method 'query' isn't defined for the type '_dashboardState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'query'.dartundefined_method

Comment: i have written query word so you can under that. In other words it would be. 
SteamBuilder(
steam:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection_name').
doc('doc_id').snapshot();
builder(context,snapshot){
return Text(snapshot.data.docs[0].get('field');
}
)

Comment: Is it StreamBuilder or SteamBuilder?